# Clear recently used fonts in Microsoft Outlook 2013

Tags: microsoft-outlook

How can I clear recently used fonts in Microsoft Outlook 2013?

Answer (score 0):

You could try clearing Most Recently Used (MRU) lists with help of OutlookTools program.
Download it here: [OutlookTools](http://www.howto-outlook.com/products/outlooktools.htm).

If you, however, want to do it manually, then MRU lists that are kept in the mail profile are stored in the following Registry key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Profiles\profile name\0a0d020000000000c000000000000046
```

More info on which keys hold which values: [Clear the Most Recently Used lists](http://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/clearmru.htm).

I could not find anything related to fonts exactly, so you will need to experiment I would guess.